# How do you make an 'if' statement do "nothing"?

Tags: c#, if-statement

Here is an example of my code. I need the last `if` to do nothing, else do something.

```
if (daPilot.Gas > 0)
    ;
else
    daPilot.failMessage3();
```

Comment: It is much easier (and far more appropriate) to make the `else` branch of the statement do nothing simply by omitting it.

Comment: thanks everybody big help

Answer (score 23):

You've already done it.  Congratulations.

Of course the far less confusing design is to just NOT the condition and then have an `if` with no `else`.

Comment: he has an extra semi colon in the statement which would cause him errors... he has not already done it.

Comment: @DotN3TDev He does not have an extra semicolon; he has exactly one *necessary* semicolon that results in his code having no errors and doing exactly what he's asking for.  He has already done it.  `if` expects to be followed by exactly one statement `;` is a statement, and it does nothing.

Comment: fair enough they would not get an error from `;`... I doubt they knew that `;` is a valid statement and put it there because they were at a loss for knowing what to do... it is not the best way to explain this answer and there are better answers that have been given that deserve the up votes... I don't get why your answer got 11 votes where other answers which are much more helpful have gotten one or none...

Comment: The empty statement with semicolon will compile, but it'll produce a warning.

Comment: @DotN3TDev If he didn't know that it was a valid statement before, he would after reading the answer.  `;` and `{}` are two ways of doing exactly the same thing; creating a no-op statement.  Some people seem to prefer the latter as a matter of personal preference of coding style, but that's all it is.  Looking through the answers I don't see any that actually *explain* anything about the semantics of `if` statements in their answers; I just see a bunch of "use this code".  Of course, neither forms of no-ops are really good style, as most answers have stated, making this largely moot.

Comment: @DavidCrowell Yes, it will produce a warning, but it will work correctly.  The warning will state that the statement does nothing, and as that is what he wants to happen, it should only confirm what he expected.  Again, the preferred design would be to reverse the conditional of the `if`, but if he doesn't want to do that, what he has will work.

Answer (score 8):

```
if (daPilot.Gas > 0) 
{
    // nothing
}                        
else
{
    daPilot.failMessage3();
}
```

Or more simply,

```
if (daPilot.Gas <= 0) 
{        
    daPilot.failMessage3();
}
```

Comment: Inverting the condition makes more sense, but if one must have a do nothing block then they should add a comment to that effect (as you have shown).

Comment: Note that if `Gas` is a single/double your code won't be equivalent to the OP's code. I find it quite common to write something like `if(!(x > y))` plus a comment to prevent people from wrongly simplifying it to `if(x <= y)`.

Answer (score 3):

Two ways:

1. Empty curlys:

   ```
   if (condition)
   {
   }
   else
   {
       method();
   }
   ```
2. Realize that you can simply invert the conditional:

   ```
    if (!condition)
       method();
   ```

Answer (score 3):

There is no point of putting a condition for doing nothing. You should do it like this.

```
if (daPilot.Gas <= 0)
    daPilot.failMessage3();
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply invert the `if` condition and declare only the `true` part:

```
if (daPilot.Gas <= 0)
    daPilot.failMessage3();
```

Anyway, you are always able to declare an empty body when needed: `{ }`.
For instance:

```
while (condition)
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Reverse the `if`:

`if (daPilot.Gas <= 0) daPilot.failMessage3();`

Answer (score 1):

You can invert `if`, try this:

```
if (daPilot.Gas <= 0)
{
    daPilot.failMessage3();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you really want it to do nothing

```
       {
            if (daPilot.Gas > 0)
            {
            }
            else
            {
              daPilot.failMessage3();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's use the `'!'` operator like:

```
if (!(daPilot.Gas > 0))
      daPilot.failMessage3();
```

or with an extra variable:

```
var isGasGreaterToZero = daPilot.Gas > 0; /*true or false*/

if(!isGasGreaterToZero)
    daPilot.failMessage3();
```

In both cases if `daPilot.Gas` is greater than zero (0) nothing will happen!

Answer (score 0):

I like the following code - it uses zero or one line but need extend to tree lines

```
#pragma warning disable CS0642 // Possible mistaken empty statement
                ;
#pragma warning restore CS0642 // Possible mistaken empty statement
```

Also use `{ }` in two lines or zero line in `if` statement:

```
if (...) { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the if statement write some code that does nothing:

if (daPilot.Gas > 0) var S = true;

Comment: better to invert the if! Also please note your code is not properly formatted in the answer.
Finally the given example really does not do anything, will therefor raise a warning.

So hence it would be better and certainly less confusing for a second reader to just write nothing.

Since you are a new contributor I see no sense in down-voting but consider removing this answer,

Answer (score 0):

I concur with the other answers here. Better to reverse the condition and if you dont want to do that, better to use the empty block `{ /* nothing */ }`.

But now, suppose you are looking for a solution that:

1. Does not reverse the condition.
2. Does not use code blocks.
3. Does not generate a warning or an error or suppress such message.
4. Has minimal impact on generated compiler code.

How can you do that?

Answer: use `_ = 0`.

I came up with the following code example which is valid in .NET 3 and 5:

```
if (new Random().Next(2) == 0)
    _ = 0; // do nothing
else
    Console.WriteLine("Do Something");
```

If you ckeck at the compiler generated IL code without optimization you see the the instruction has been replaced by a `nop`.

[image]

With optimizations, the condition has been reversed by the compiler and the then part of the conditional is completely optimized away.

[image]

Conclusion: `_ = 0;` fits the bill.